# Euler 357 solution efficiency

Tags: ruby, programming-challenge, primes, time-limit-exceeded

I have a Ruby program which should solve the following problem:

> Consider the divisors of 30: 1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30. It can be seen that
>   for every divisor d of 30, d+30/d is prime.
>
> Find the sum of all positive integers n not exceeding 100 000 000 such
>   that for every divisor d of n, d+n/d is prime.

```
require 'prime'

class Integer
    def factors # returns an array of all factors of self
        return (1..self).collect { |n| n if ((self/n) * n) == self }.compact
    end
end

puts "Started at #{Time.now}."
counter = 0

1.upto(100000000) do |n|
    factors = n.factors
    counter += n if factors.all? { |d| ( (d+n) / d ).is_a? Prime }
end

p counter
puts "Ended at #{Time.now}."
```

Problem is, while the code runs, it takes so long (not finished after several hours) that I can't actually test if I get the right answer. Is there any way to make the code more efficient so that it completes in a shorter amount of time? The problem is [question #357 of Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=357). All Euler problems should take less than one minute to solve if an efficient algorithm is being used.

Comment: Precompute primes.

Comment: Think about how even numbers will behave.  Think about how odd numbers will behave.  @Veedrac's suggestion is good as well.

Comment: Have you tested if for smaller values, at least? It seems to always return 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n.is_a? Prime
```

Doesn't work. I don't know enough Ruby to tell you why, but it doesn't. Use `Prime.prime?` instead.

Further, `(d + n) / d` is not the right calculation. You want `d + n/d`.

You can simplify

```
return (1..self).collect { |n| n if ((self/n) * n) == self }.compact
```

to

```
(1..self).select { |n| self / n * n == self }
```

which is even simpler as

```
(1..self).select { |n| (self % n).zero? }
```

One can do even better by making this lazy:

```
(1..self).lazy.select { |n| (self % n).zero? }
```

Then one can precompute the primes for later:

```
primes = Array.new(max+1) { |i| false }
Prime.each do |n|
    break if n > max
    primes[n] = true
end

1.upto(max) do |n|
    factors = n.factors
    counter += n if factors.all? { |d| primes[d + n/d] }
end
```

One can also note that only numbers one below primes actually need to be checked, since `1` is a factor of every number. This simplifies things:

```
primes = Array.new(max+1) { |i| false }
Prime.each do |prime|
    break if prime > max
    primes[prime] = true

    n = prime - 1
    factors = n.factors    
    counter += n if factors.all? { |d| primes[d + n/d] }
end
```

One also only need the first square root of factors, since larger numbers are paired with the smaller numbers anyway:

```
(1..Math.sqrt(self) + 1).lazy.select { |n| (self % n).zero? }
```

This now takes about 100 seconds for `n = 100_000_000`.

Comment: I'm getting the right answer. Here's the code in full: https://gist.github.com/Veedrac/1e95a577078410d32de5.

Comment: Mine is pretty much word for word? https://gist.github.com/Aiishe/e82c2681317d41becbeb
Let's play find the typo ;)

Comment: Whatever, I copy/pasted yours and it's working. Didn't find the error in my version.
Thanks very much for helping to improve this, and pointing out the mistakes with n.is_a? Prime and my formula, but I don't really understand the reasoning behind your changes, e.g "One can also note that only numbers one below primes actually need to be checked, since 1 is a factor of every number." Is this advanced math or am I really dumb?

Comment: @Nemo You wrote `n = prime = 1`

Comment: @Nemo A number `k` has a factor `1`, so `1 + k/1` must be prime.

Comment: Still not clicking. What if `k` was `7`? `1 + 7/1 = 8`, 8 is not prime.

Comment: Yes, but `7` doesn't satisfy that "for every divisor d of 7, d+7/d is prime" so we don't want it. We want the number *below* `7`.

Comment: @Nemo could you please remove your comment with the numerical answer to the problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the prime factorization of each number as you check it.  You can use the prime factorization of n to quickly produce a list of divisors of n, without testing all numbers from 1 to n.

One common method to do this is to produce an array of ints, A[], with the properties:

- A[n] <= n
- if A[n] == n, then n is prime
- if A[n] < n, then A[n] is a prime factor of n

You can then use A[] to quickly determine if n is prime, and recursively put together its prime factorization if it is not.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Could you include an example?

Comment: It's a basic variation on a prime sieve.